# SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future. Set it to True to suppress this warning

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting above error in my flask programme. I am using Flask-SQLALCHEMY - 2.4.1 with Pycharm editor.
Please help to solve this problem. I am wasted my lot of time on it.

```
UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

Answer (score 9):

The line that you'll need is:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

Put it before the SQLAlchemy() call. You can change `app` with your correspondent Flask object name.

Answer (score 2):

It's a warning meaning that in the future the code may break.

Please make a habit of reading the error messages

`SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` can be **set to False** and the error will vanish.

The second warning is basically about using a seperate web server than the built in flask web server.

To mitigate this you would need to use a *production grade* web server like gunicorn or Apache web server